# jquery $ function returning different results in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.Schedule .Full input').each(function(i)
 {
        var controls = $('.Morning input, .MorningPart input, .Afternoon input, .AfternoonPart input', $(this).parents('.Schedule'));
        alert(controls.length + " Conflicting Controls\n"+
              $(this).parents('.Schedule').attr('id') + " Parent");
 });
```

When I run this code in Firefox the first execution of this function produces an alert box saying the following:

> 17 Conflicting Controls 
>  Monday Parent

The exact same page run in IE 6 or 7 produces an alert box saying the following:

> 45 Conflicting Controls 
>  Monday Parent

Firefox is right, there are only 17 conflicting controls. The 45 that IE is identifying are controls that are not a descendant of "Monday". If I've specified "Monday" as the context for the $() function, why is IE returning controls outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
var controls = $(this).parents('.Schedule').children('.Morning input, .MorningPart input, .Afternoon input, .AfternoonPart input')
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your example a bit because my structure is a little different

```
$(this).parents('.RadioSchedule').children('.Morning, .MorningPart, .Afternoon, .AfternoonPart').find('input');
```

this worked produced the same results across IE and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="Monday" class="Schedule">
    <div class="Full">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="MondayFullDay" checked="checked" value="none"/>None 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Tuesday" class="Schedule">
    <div class="Full">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="TuesdayFullDay" checked="checked" value="none"/>None 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Okay here's another tricky part... Looks like

```
$(this).parents('.Schedule');
```

is returning incrementally more results as it gets executed. So when it's executed the first time for MondayFullDay it returns 1 result, but once it gets to TuesdayFullDay it returns 2 results. This is only in IE.

Because the above xhtml structure is not optional for this application, I ended up just manually traversing the DOM through successive calls to .parent().

Changing this

```
$(this).parents('.Schedule');
```

Into this

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent();
```

I'm still convinced that the parents() method is not working as documented though...

Comment: I believe .parents() will return basically the entire structure of the document above the current node including the top level body node.  This is vs .parent() which will only return the direct parent. 

If 'this' is the input node you may have more luck with $(this).parent().parent().parent() (although it's pretty fugly looking and would need to change if your html structure changed)